# type of types in Java

Tags: c#, java, types, primitive-types

At the risk of asking a question that has already been asked but

is there a counterpart in Java for the `Type` type available in C# ?

What I want to do is filling an array with elements which reflect several primitive types such as *int*, *byte* etc.

In C# it would be the following code:

```
Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(byte), typeof(short) };
```

Comment: pendant = a counterpart; a similar construct available in Java as it is available in C#.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but where do you get that definition of "pendant"?  I've never heard that usage.  You may be turning off readers by using an esoteric word when apt alternatives exist.  Just a thought.

Comment: well ... I am not a native English speaker. In German, which my mother tongue the word "Pendant" is rather common. To be honest I was simply wrong when looking into my English dictionary .. I will substitute by something more common :)

Comment: No worries.  For what it's worth, your English is probably 1000x better than my German!  (Hint:  I don't speak any German!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, these are available through their wrapper's [`TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) fields:

```
Class[] types = new Class[] {Integer.TYPE, Byte.TYPE, ...};
```

You can also use `int.class` syntax, which has not been available in earlier versions of the language:

```
Class[] types = new Class[] {int.class, byte.class, ...}; // Lowercase is important
```

Comment: Worked like a charme - Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about:

```
Class[] aClass = {Integer.class, Short.class, Byte.class};
```

However, to emphasize the difference with `Integer.TYPE` and `Integer.class`:  `Integer.TYPE` is in fact a `Class<Integer>` type and: `Integer.TYPE`  is equivalent to `int.class`

```
System.out.println(Integer.class == Integer.TYPE); // false
System.out.println(Integer.TYPE == int.class); // true
```

Comment: Unlike in C#, a primitive numeric type in Java is not equivalent to its framework-level/boxed type.  `Integer.class` is not equivalent to `int.class` (or `Integer.TYPE`), though `typeof(int)` is equivalent to `typeof(System.Int32)`.  So your answer is likely to cause some confusion based on the types in the OP's example.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, I have also mentioned that in the answer. Actually i was late about mentioning `int.class` and such and when i have found other poster has already written it, i omitted the discussion to avoid cluttering. However, updated the answer to emphasize your opinion :)

Comment: Thank you very much - your help is pretty much appreciated.